# How to make Intel GPU available for processing through pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, gpu, intel

I'm using a laptop which has Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520.
Does anyone know how to it set up for Deep Learning, specifically Pytorch? I have seen if you have Nvidia graphics I can install cuda but what to do when you have intel GPU?

Comment: AFAIK, there is nothing you can do. You'll have to use the cpu version.

Answer (score 15):

PyTorch doesn't support anything other than NVIDIA CUDA and lately AMD Rocm.
Intels support for Pytorch that were given in the other answers is exclusive to xeon line of processors and its not that scalable either with regards to GPUs.
Intel's `oneAPI` formerly known ad `oneDNN` however, has support for a wide range of hardwares including intel's integrated graphics but at the moment, the full support is not yet implemented in PyTorch as of 10/29/2020 or PyTorch 1.7.
But you still have other options. for inference you have couple of options.
[DirectML](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectML) is one of them. basically you convert your model into [onnx](https://github.com/onnx/onnx), and then use directml provider to run your model on gpu (which in our case will use DirectX12 and works only on Windows for now!)

Your other Option is to use [OpenVino](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/index.html) and [TVM](https://github.com/apache/incubator-tvm) both of which support multi platforms including Linux, Windows, Mac, etc.
OpenVino and TVM use ONNX models so you need to first convert your model to onnx format and then use them.

Lately(as of 2023),[IREE (Intermediate Representation Execution Environment)](https://iree-org.github.io/iree/) ([torch-mlir](https://github.com/llvm/torch-mlir) in this case) can be used as well.

Comment: Should be "Intel's `oneDNN` formerly known as `mklDNN`...."

Comment: Seems they have changed the github repo's name back to `oneDNN` again but in the description they still refer to it as oneAPI. They changed this several times from mkldnn, to oneDNN to oneAPI and now they themselves seem to be unsure of 1which name to pick ultimately so they went with both I guess!

Comment: Was the technology in this video RocM or something else? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hvYSt4AUeJg

Comment: @pete: no, its not ROCm, ROCm is not publicly supported on windows yet!
what you see in that link uses [nod-ai's `SHARK`](https://github.com/nod-ai/SHARK) which works on both Nvidia and AMD cards.

Comment: @Hossein Thank you but what I meant was what is SHARK using? How are they able to run it on AMD cards if not by ROCm, or directML, or some other framework? And how could I replicate what they did for other models such as GPT-Neo?

Comment: @pete It uses [torch-mlir](https://github.com/llvm/torch-mlir) behind the scene which in turn uses [IREE (Intermediate Representation Execution Environment)](https://iree-org.github.io/iree/) to do this. currently it supports, pytorch,tensorflow,jax and supports all major OSes (windows,linux,macos,anroid and ios).

Comment: I am a newbie to ML. Can someone list steps on how to use GPU acceleration in pytorch on my Macbook with Intel integrated graphics?

Answer (score 8):

Intel provides optimized libraries for Deep and Machine Learning if you are using one of their later processors. A starting point would be [this post](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/getting-started-with-intel-optimization-of-pytorch.html), which is about getting started with Intel optimization of PyTorch. They provide more information about this in their AI workshops.