# Train transformer model with low performance

Tags: python, gpu, translation, huggingface-transformers, transformer-model

I am following this [tutorial](https://huggingface.co/course/chapter7/4?) to try to train data to translate a language, however using only my cpu, I have to wait 5 hours to train the data (and after these 5 hours the process is killed because it uses too many resources). Here is my configuration:

- Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
- OS Type: 64-bit
- Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-7500T CPU @ 2.70GHz
- Memory: 7,5 Gio
- GPU:Intel HD Graphics 630

so i tried to see how i can use my gpu to train my model, but unfortunately pytorch only supports cuda, but i saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64593792/how-to-make-intel-gpu-available-for-processing-through-pytorch) that referred to this [tool](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/guide/getting-started-with-intel-optimization-of-pytorch.html), however after installing (I have do `python -m pip install torch_ipex==1.9.0 -f https://software.intel.com/ipex-whl-stable`) it, i get this error:

```
ImportError: /home/USER/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch_ipex/lib/libtorch_ipex.so: undefined symbol: _ZN2at20hinge_embedding_lossERKNS_6TensorES2_dl
```

You can help me to solve this error or give me the link of a pre-entrainer dataset containing several languages that makes accurate translations (using t5, the quality is not incredible, for example it translates "hello world" to "bonjour monde" in French (the good translation is "bonjour le monde") :D.

Comment: The i5 is not a hot performing processor, and it is a long stretch to call the HD Graphics 630 a GPU at all.  You must have some kind of version mismatch; it's missing `at::hinge_embedding_loss`, which is probably an Intel Analytics Toolkit function, but it's being called from an Intel DLL.  Why did you pick version 1.9.0?  Isn't 1.10.0 available?

Comment: I had not paid attention to the version, otherwise for the performance I worked on google colabs. Thanks for your answer