# Intel Graphics card for PyTorch acceleration

Tags: pytorch, gpu, opencl

I have a HP laptop with an Intel graphics card (Iris Xe, I think, based on the following:

```
lspci -vnn | grep VGA
0000:00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] [8086:9a49] (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

though I honestly don't know what all of that means). I would like to use this GPU for deep learning with PyTorch to avoid paying for online resources like Google Colab. I know PyTorch currently supports Nvidia GPUs with CUDA and Apple silicon. I found [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ai/directml/gpu-pytorch-wsl) with instructions on how I could use directML to do this on WSL. The problem is that this laptop runs Linux (Mint, specifically). It seems to me that if something works on WSL, it should be easy to adapt to work on native Linux, but I'm not seeing any resources online for that and can't get it to work myself.

I also see many pages recommending OpenCL to use PyTorch with GPUs other than Nvidia, but based on what I've read, this would require a significant amount of work and would have a steep learning curve since I don't even know what OpenCL is.

TL;DR: The question, in sum, is: Can I (and how can I) use my Intel graphics card for PyTorch hardware acceleration?
Note: this question is not a duplicate of any questions I've found about using alternative GPUs than Nvidia ones for PyTorch, because I am specifically wondering how I can use directML or OpenCL on my operating system.

I'll add that when I installed torch_directml with pip, and tried to import it, I got this error:

```
In [1]: import torch_directml
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 1
----> 1 import torch_directml

File /usr/lib/python3.10/torch_directml/__init__.py:13
     11 else:
     12     directml_dll = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'libdirectml.so')
---> 13 torch.ops.load_library(directml_dll)
     15 # import native apis
     16 import torch_directml_native

File ~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_ops.py:573, in _Ops.load_library(self, path)
    568 path = _utils_internal.resolve_library_path(path)
    569 with dl_open_guard():
    570     # Import the shared library into the process, thus running its
    571     # static (global) initialization code in order to register custom
    572     # operators with the JIT.
--> 573     ctypes.CDLL(path)
    574 self.loaded_libraries.add(path)

File /usr/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py:374, in CDLL.__init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    371 self._FuncPtr = _FuncPtr
    373 if handle is None:
--> 374     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    375 else:
    376     self._handle = handle

OSError: libd3d12.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

even though the libd3d12.so file is present in the torch_directml folder. My guess is this is related to a problem with installation or with the fact that by all I can find, DirectML is intended for Windows or WSL, not native Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make Intel GPU available for processing through pytorch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64593792/how-to-make-intel-gpu-available-for-processing-through-pytorch)